# Combining css with php - 2 vhost with same configuration but different results - loadproxy_fcgi:error

Tags: php, css, apache

I have a php file to combine css files that i use since years and it always worked.
Now i did setup a new test server with latest Debian, Apache 2.4.25 MPM Event and PHP 7.2.
I have two vhost that except for the domain are the same:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName balkenhantel.testb
   DocumentRoot /var/www/balkenhantel

   <Directory /var/www/balkenhantel>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
      AllowOverride All
      Options -Indexes
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName eks-services.testb
   DocumentRoot /var/www/eks-services

   <Directory /var/www/eks-services>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
      AllowOverride All
      Options -Indexes
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Both sites have the link to the css like this in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/design/css/css-fb201704032623.php" />
```

I did check the .htaccess and the css.php with WinMerge and they are the same.

The css.php:

```
<?php
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
header('Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8');
header('X-Powered-By: ');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])). ' GMT', true, 200);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 2592000) . ' GMT'); // 1 month

define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PATH_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);

$cssPath = PATH_ROOT;

//css path | css file name | css browser1
//css browser = "all" for all browser, "browser1,browser2,..." for defined various browser only
//IE = msie 6
//IE with various version = msie parent version or full version, e.g. "msie 6" or "msie 5.5" or "msie 5.0.1"
//IE 4 = msie 4
//IE 5 = msie 5
//IE 6 = msie 6
//IE 7 = msie 7
//Opera = opera
//Opera with various version = opera/version, e.g. "opera/9.10"
//Firefox = firefox
//Firefox with various version = firefox/version, e.g. "firefox/2.0.0.14"

$cssGZIP[] = $cssPath."|reset.css|all";
$cssGZIP[] = $cssPath."|structure.css|all";
$cssGZIP[] = $cssPath."|content.css|all";
$cssGZIP[] = $cssPath."|gadgets.css|all";
$cssGZIP[] = $cssPath."|fancyforms.css|all";

foreach($cssGZIP as $GZIP) {
    $css = explode("|", $GZIP);
    if($css[2]=="all") {
    if(file_exists($css[0].$css[1])) {
        $buffer .= file_get_contents($css[0].$css[1]);
    }
    } else {
        $browsers = explode(",", $css[2]);
        $loadThisCSS = false;
        foreach($browsers as $browser) {
            if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), $browser) !== false) {
               $loadThisCSS = true;
            }
        }
        if($loadThisCSS == true) {
            if(file_exists($css[0].$css[1])) {
            $buffer .= file_get_contents($css[0].$css[1]);
            }
       }
   }
}

// Remove comments
$buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);

// Remove space after colons
$buffer = str_replace(': ', ':', $buffer);

// Remove whitespace
$buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);

echo($buffer);
?>
```

The funny thing is that on one site the css does not work. It gets loaded but does not work. I also can call it in the browser and it shows up.
Even more funny is that on the second site where the css works i have a error:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: buffer in /var/www/eks-services/design/css/css.php on line 37\n', referer: http://eks-services.testb/
```

Comment: Please explain "It gets loaded but does not work". You mean you can see your CSS code when accessing the source file but it doesn't apply the styles to the page?

Comment: @Capsul exactly that was/is the behavior. But as i wrote below, i saw now that only the last css (fancyforms.css) is loaded and it seems to be a FBM problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says on line 37 you are concatenating `.=` a variable without defining it first. You cannot do this in php and you first need to define your variable.

Define `$buffer` sooner and that will solve this problem.

```
$buffer = '';
if(file_exists($css[0].$css[1])) {
    $buffer .= file_get_contents($css[0].$css[1]);
}
```

As for why it's working on one server and not the other perhaps you are overlooking something or maybe they are running different versions of php. I'm not sure if older versions allowed you to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's one server. That's why i don't get where the different result come from.

Comment: Now i realized that only the last css is loaded. I checked the php version from the provider server and it's 7.0.29 CGI/FastCGI. My test server is 7.2 FPM/FastCGI. My old test server was 5.3.3 CGI. So FPM is the problem.

Comment: It's just a notice. It's bad practice to not declare your vars but the code will still run. You'd get a Fatal error otherwise. In this case, PHP just defines the variable for you before doing the concatenation. The fact you see the error in one the second site is probably because the error reporting is configured differentley (shows E_NOTICE while the other doesn't)

Comment: As a matter of fact, I would check the error_log on the other one (if any) to understand why it fails.

Comment: Sure i already did check both (it's one log) and that php notice for that one site is the only error in the apache log. The FastCGI Process Manager is eating my css :-(

Comment: It's getting more funny. I changed the one that first did not work to php5.6 and it started working. But i need to remove the versioning (-fb201704032623). If i don't do that i get: proxy_fcgi:error Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'. After switching back to php7.2 it still works even with the versioning. But no matter what i do, the site that first worked doesn't now.

Comment: Sounds like a versioning problem. You're getting into a different question that's hard to answer in the comments. You might have better luck writing another question.